# jQuery - closest input to current input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs with same class names with one input inside each. First one has id, second - no, I need get closest input to my input with id. I can't set an id to second input, or change class names of divs.

HTML -

```
<div class="picker">
     <input id="myInput"/>
</div>
<div class="picker">
     <input/> <-- which I need to get ->
</div>
```

I have tried to use something like below, but, this operation returns me the first input.

```
$("#myInput").closest("input")
```

Comment: closest walks up the tree. you are not walking up the tree. input is not going to be a parent of input.

Comment: `closest` isn't the ideal name: it means "closest parent", not "nearest in the html source".  However, this is noted on both https://api.jquery.com/closest/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to pick parent the "picker" and then you need to pick the next "picker" and then find the input.

```js
const inp = $("#myInput").closest('.picker').next('.picker').find('input');
inp.val('found it');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="picker">
  <input id="myInput" />
</div>
<div class="picker">
  <input/>
  <-- which I need to get ->
</div>
```

Comment: That works, thank you. But only one question, how to solve this issue if between those two divs, there is also a div?

Comment: I solved it by adding additional .next() to chain. Thank you!